# System.EntryPointNotFoundException in Parallel red in output

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I had some minor problem but I cant seem to see where its gone wrong , could someone help me out:

Loadassembly fn

```
public static Assembly LoadAssembly(string assemblyfile)
        {
            Assembly library;
            using (var fs = File.Open(assemblyfile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    library = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return library;
        }

public static string[] GetDLLInfo(string assemblyfile, bool onlyNameSpace)
            {
                var strAssembly = LoadAssembly(assemblyfile).GetTypes();
                List<string> classList = new List<string>();

                var xx = strAssembly.Select(t => t.Namespace).Distinct().ToList();
                var nmSpaceLiStrings = xx.ToArray();

                Parallel.ForEach(nmSpaceLiStrings, x =>
                {
                    var types = strAssembly.Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == x).ToList();
                    types.ForEach(t => classList.Add(t.FullName));
                });

                /* foreach (var x in nmSpaceLiStrings)
                {
                    var types = strAssembly.Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == x).ToList();
                    types.ForEach(t => classList.Add(t.FullName));
                } */

                if (onlyNameSpace)
                {
                    return nmSpaceLiStrings;
                }
                return classList.ToArray();
            }
```

Its kind of weird if I use 'foreach' (not parallel , I got no warning in output dialog, but when I use 'parallel' I got :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Does my parallel gone wrong and show me the correct way?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the class names to a list, have you tried using ConcurrentBag<T>?

Comment: Im newbie in c# tho...so my ear still not used such advance term, thanks for info , ill try to research it today ?

Answer (score 0):

What is LoadAssembly method? How it's declared? The exception means that some method does not exist in the dll. So the problem is in the assembly itself or in the LoadAssembly declaration.

Comment: Load assembly method just loading dynamically load dll via reflection, using stream,etc..I tried to erase 'Parallel.ForEach xxxx' and try using foreach , it return just fine no note, but when I using 'Parallel' it return just fine with note "A first chance exception of type xxx"....

Comment: Thnks Vitaly for the comment, this is Loadassemblly

Comment: So on the problem is there. Different reasons may be - check the declaration for first.